# Javascript - Launch function, after previous function has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to launch a function after the previous functions has ended.
The .SideArea div, is going to display: none efter the animation of .sideShowing, #page has ended, but instead the display:none part is ignored.

Heres my code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#SideMenuButton").click(function() {
        var SideArea = $(".SideArea");
        if (SideArea.css('display')!=='block') {
            SideArea.css('display','block');
            var move = 260;
            $(".sideShowing #page").stop().animate({left:"+="+move},{queue:false,duration:150});
            $("body, #viewport").css('min-height','600px').css('max-height','600px');
        } else {
            $(".sideShowing #page").stop().animate({left:"0"},{queue:false,duration:150}, function() {
                $(".SideArea").css('display','none')});

            $("body, #viewport").css('min-height','800px').css('max-height','');
        }
    });
});
```

It is the

```
$(".sideShowing #page").stop().animate({left:"0"},{queue:false,duration:150}, function() {
                $(".SideArea").css('display','none')});
```

part, where the display: none is ignored. I want the function to start when the previous animate-function has ended but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is the intended behaviour of `queueu:false`. Maybe you want to remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this form of `animate()`, the `complete` callback is specified as a property of the  second argument (the options map), not as a third argument.

```
$(".sideShowing #page").stop().animate({left:"0"}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 150,
    complete: function() {
        $SideArea.css('display','none');
    }
});
```